# problems configuring Filezilla ftp server on windows azure virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, ftp

Recently I've been attempting to setup a filezilla server on one of azure virtual machines and cannot seem to get it fully running. I am currently able to get an initial connection, however subsequent data connections (i.e. for listing remote directories, file transfers etc..) always fail. I have tried following the advice on various blogs like this one:

http://www.bradmcallister.com/posts/how-to-use-filezilla-ftp-server-with-windows-azure-virtual-machines/

however I still get the same results.

### Azure manager settings

unfortuantely I don't have enough reputation to post pictures of the configuration, so I will try my best to describe them.

for the server I have 2 Endpoints open for ftp.

- TCP public port: 21, private port: 21
- TCP public port: 65100, private port: 65100

### General server settings

For the purpose of eliminating potential sources of errors I have temporarily turned off windows firewall on the server, so that should not affect the results that I'm seeing here.

### FileZilla PASV settings

- use custom port range checked. range used was 65100 - 65100
- use the following IP checked, with the public virtual IP (VIP) Address from the azure dashboard.
- Don't use external IP for local connections unchecked

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntKeh.jpg

### Connection Attempt Log

```
Status: Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
Response:   220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
Response:   220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
Command:    USER x
Response:   331 Password required for x
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   230 Logged on
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (XXX,XXX,XXX,43,254,76)
Command:    MLSD
Response:   425 Can't open data connection.
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Thanks,

Yabbi

Comment: +1 thanks for posting this! I was missing the passive settings to make my vm work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to finally figure this out after a lot of head scratching. Turns out that azure has implemented a probing of sorts on ports opened using the manager. deleting the passive ports created there and opening them up using powershell allowed this to work.

Here's a good article describing the process: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/8f697f17-72b7-46f7-8c97-398b91190a2f/server-2012-vm-on-azure-passive-ftp-wont-work

Comment: FYI, we have an update coming soon that will make it easier to manage probes for endpoints. Once it's available, the behavior of default probing will be removed.

Comment: I am able to install filezilla in the windows azure and connect inside the server as FTP 127.0.0.1. However I am not able to connect from outside. What could be the issue. I followed the same instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Short summary of what can fix this issue. Worked for me.

1. **Azure VM - Firewall**

   1.1) Open Inbound port 21

   1.2) Open few Inbound ports for Passive mode - Say 1035 to 1040
2. **Azure VM - FileZilla Server**

   2.1) In settings - Change Passive ports to 1035 to 1040 ( or what ever ports you opened in 1.2 above )

   2.2) For "External Server IP" option, use "Retrieve external IP address from"
3. **Azure Control Panel - Endpoints**

   3.1) Open port 21, and 1035 to 1040 ( or what ever ports you opened in 1.2 above )

Comment: Works like charm! For my case, I used port 60000 instead, because it was allowed by default by my Azure Network Group and VM

Answer (score 1):

Goto settings of filezilla.

change the FTP setting.

instead of passive mode -- select active mode and click ok.

try now it will work.

azure doesn't allow passive ftp, thats the head scratching thing here.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me! Thank you. I was trying to connect to one of Azure VMs via another one.

Answer (score -1):

I decided that I can make it on my own, but got same error as in the queston. But then I googled a little (also saw this question), few hours of trying some manuals, and, finnaly here I found working thing!
Hope it helps to other people 
http://itq.nl/walkthrough-hosting-ftp-on-iis-7-5-a-windows-azure-vm-2/